# como puedo obtener una lista con las longitudes de tramos de otra lista?

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for

tengo una pregunta. tengo 2 listas:

```
b= [3, 6, ]

c= [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Quiero: obtener una lista con las longitudes de los valores de `c` hasta llegar a cada uno de los valores de `b`, esto es: `c` primero toma 3 valores para llegar hasta el primer valor de `b ---> 0,1,2` hasta llegar al valor 3. Después toma 2 valores, 4 y 5 para llegar al 6. La lista que debería obtener seria:
`d=[3,2]`.

Antes de las longitudes supongo que serviría  obtener las listas: `[0,1,2]` y `[4,5]` y después calcular sus longitudes. quise hacer eso en el código siguiente, pero me devuelve una lista empezando siempre desde el primer valor de la lista `c`. Esto es: **el código de abajo me devuelve**: `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]`.

```
b=[3, 6]
c=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
for j in b:
    for k in c:
        if k < j:
            files.append(k)
        else:
            break
print((files))
print(len(files))
```

Tall vez haya una manera de calcular las longitudes directamente, pero no se como.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hace falta usar mas de un ciclo `for`, esto solo para iterar en la lista `b`. Suponiendo que el numero antes del indicado, ejemplo `6` donde `5` esta en `c`, se puede hacer de forma muy fácil, podemos coger los elementos usando *slices* `[inicio:fin]`, donde el inicio será `0` y el final el numero de elementos a coger.

```py
b=[3, 6]
c=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]

ini = 0 #desde donde va a coger la lista
d = []
for n in b:
    try:
        fin = c.index(n-1)+1 #obtenemos la posicion del elemento
        longitud = len(c[ini:fin])
        ini = fin #el inicio sera el ultimo elemento que cogimos
        d.append(longitud)
    except:
        print("Ha ocurrido un error") #en caso ocurra un error

print(d)
```

Reemplazamos la variable inicio, por que sino cogeríamos los números desde el `0` y par atener registro de donde nos quedamos asignamos a la variable inicio el valor del ultimo elemento que cogimos, para que en la próxima iteración empiece desde ahí.

**resultado**

```
[3, 2]
```

Comment: hola. grcias por la respuesta, pero me devuelve el error: invalid syntax con except: , y si saco el except y el print me devuelve:  unexpected EOF while parsing. que puede estar mal en el codigo?

Comment: Jajaja, me olvide cerrar un paréntesis en `d.append(long)` corrige eso y te funcionará

Comment: jajaja no lo habia visto, ahora funciona y me devuelve [3,2]. pero hay un problema en el codigo y es que: si yo por ejemplo cambio b y c. agregandole algunos valores: b=[3, 6,9]
c=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5,7,8] , me devuelve : d=[3,3,1] , cuando deberia devolverme [3,2,2]. que podria estar mal en el codigo? grcias!

Comment: eso pasa por que estamos escogiendo desde una posicion hasta otra, y al no existir los numeros de la lista `b` en `c` se vuelve algo complicado, ya he editado la respuesta.

Comment: funciona!grcias!

Answer (score -1):

De una forma general para solucionar el problema que planteas se puede resolver usando el método pop de una lista de la siguiente forma:

```
b=[3, 6]
c=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
files = []

for vb in b:
    n = 0
    done = False
    while not done:    
        if c:
            vc = c.pop(0)
        else: 
            files.append(n + 1)
            done = True
        if vc > vb: 
            files.append(n)
            done = True
        n += 1
```

Comment: hola. grcias por la respuesta, para esas 2 listas b y c funciona, pero no funciona si agrego un numero mas a cada lista: si pongo: b=[3, 6, 8]
c=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7] , deberia darme: files=[3,2,1], pero devuelve:[3,1,1]. que puede estar mal en el codigo? grcias!